# Get category name from related entry

Tags: relationships

I've got a entry called "town" with a native relationship field, the field name is "parks" and it relates to a channel of entries of parks! Each "Park" has a category too.

In my template i'm showing my "Town" entry and i want to display the related "park" and it's category.

But, i don't seem to be having much luck with it.

My code is as follows:

```
{exp:channel:entries dynamic="off"}
{parks}{categories}{category_name}{/categories}{/parks}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

But i've also tried:

```
{parents field="parks"}{categories}{category_name}{/categories}{/parents}
```

I'm sure i'm just being a cretin here, any help would be lovely, cheers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to prefix the categories loop with the related field name like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries dynamic="no"}
    {parks}{parks:categories}{category_name}{/parks:categories}{/parks}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This is to allow you flexibility to display the parent entry's categories too, so it's quite handy.

Comment: Awesome, just bloody awesome :)